# I question the use of "question" in question titles

Tags: discussion, editing, question-titles, buzzwords

The search:

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Aquestion

brings up some 63 odd questions. Some of them are closed, some are actually pertaining to specific questions on particular exams, but most are suffering from having a poor and/or non-descriptive title.

This is no emergency, but it would be nice to have descriptive, googleable titles for these so that people can find them in the future.  Admittedly, some of them are regular homework questions without much else, but extracting a concept from them for the title would still be helpful so that we can catalog them accordingly.

So, if you're bored on a rainy Tuesday, or stuck in the waiting room at the dentist, please grab a couple of them and polish them up, if you would.

Comment: It always gives me shivers when I see it, try to give it more descriptive titles, but for some of these it just seems impossible...

Comment: It's definitely challenging for some of them, I agree.  If it's hopeless to come up with one, it's okay to just leave it.

Comment: I'll do a couple :)

Comment: I have already done a couple of them, going from high to low votes. And I shall continue this quest :D

Comment: @Martin Carry on, then!  Thanks for all that you do! :)

Comment: I have done a bunch as well. My feeling is that the ones that are really hard to turn into a specific question actually ought to be closed.

Comment: @Michiel I would tend to agree in most cases.  Feel free to cast a close vote on them to send them into the queue and we can see what the community thinks.

Comment: I cleaned up the last of them (all closed).

Comment: Thanks @BenNorris!  I will be pursuing my copyright on the title. :)

Comment: Can I join in over here and over [there](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/566/houston-we-have-a-problem-in-question-titles) since the search still yields results?

Comment: @DelPate Absolutely.  Editing is a fluid process, it's never quite done!  Glad to have you contributing.