# Help make help questions have more helpful titles

Tags: discussion, editing, question-titles, buzzwords

In the vein of [this meta post](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/524/i-question-the-use-of-question-in-question-titles?cb=1), here are some 21 questions with the word "help" in the title.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Ahelp

Some of these asking for help with specific problems can probably benefit from a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is done now. The remaining two questions use the work help in a proper context, so I left them untouched.

Answer (score 1):

I think in these cases, the help word is unhelpful and do not affect the person who are going to help. If you really want help and get an answer for you question. Make the title straight to the point without the help.