# Houston, we have a "Problem" in question titles

Tags: discussion, editing, question-titles, buzzwords

So we are all familiar with the drill, given through the following:

- [I question the use of "question" in question titles](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/524/4945)
- [Help make help questions have more helpful titles](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/549/4945)

There are currently 34 uses of "problem" in titles which could benefit from some more descriptive headings:

- https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Aproblem

So if you are bored enough, please head on over and give it a try.

Comment: For me, it makes the question more like from their homework

Comment: I have worked through several. There are now 19.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's efforts thus far! :D

Comment: These have all been done: the only remaining one is [How was the quantum 3-Body problem solved?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/4438/7412), which clearly needs the P-word there. :-)

Comment: @DavidRicherby True enough, thanks everyone for your efforts and keep an eye open for these kind of buzzwords.

Comment: At least you don't have a [porblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161398/houston-we-have-a-porblem) yet.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the "problem" has grown since this request was first posted to meta.

I'm working through some of these, especially some of the "richer" questions that better contribute to the site (and then later I'll hit up more of the homework ones.)

Comment: Excellent! I tackled a couple of *questions* and *problems* in titles too in my last edit session. Don't forget to leave a a couple of these open for the guys that will complain about your efforts while they have ignored the problem :D