# Buzzwords in question titles - season 4 & 5 - experiments and exercises

Tags: discussion, editing, question-titles, buzzwords

I was looking for a pun in the question title, but was unable to find one. So instead let us remember the previous seasons:

1. [I question the use of "question" in question titles](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/524/4945) ([search here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Aquestion))
2. [Help make help questions have more helpful titles](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/549/4945) ([search here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Ahelp))
3. [Houston, we have a "Problem" in question titles](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/566/4945) ([search here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Aproblem))

There are currently <strike>19</strike> some uses of "experiment" in titles. Some of them are legit uses, like "[Is the vinegar and baking soda experiment safe for children?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/2813/4945)". Some of them have (at the moment) rather meaningles titles, like "[Titration experiment](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/6558/4945)" or "[Experiment with batteries](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/883/4945)". (This has been changed by now). A couple of them could benefit from some more descriptive headings:

- https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Aexperiment

Another buzzword I'd like to question is "exercise". But there are thankfully not a lot of uses out there. For the sake of completeness:

- https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Aexercise+

Another thing I would like to add is that fighting the buzzwords in titles is a battle we might never be able to win. Especially when it comes to "help" and "questions", they will pop up any time and anywhere. If you are editing, please try to remove the buzzwords.

So if you are bored enough, please head on over and give it a try. ***Pretty please.***

Last, but nowhere least, I want to give a shout out to

- [Can we edit out unnecessary "statements of weakness" or buzzwords inside the questions' bodies?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/593/4945)

When you clicked on the edit link already, adding math and chem formulas, remove all the gutter you find. Keep the quality high. And since this is meta: ***THANK YOU!***

Comment: I'm bored now...

Comment: Shout out to: http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/2736/4945

Comment: I went through the question questions , question can be provided with a title but "question**s**" are multiple questions under one single question. Is it preferred to leave "questions" in the title or the main topic they are about.

Comment: @AvatarShiny ideally there is only one question pretty post, if there are more, there is something else wrong with it, too. When in doubt flag it, or ask|post in one of the chats