# Can we edit out unnecessary "statements of weakness" or buzzwords inside the questions' bodies?

Tags: discussion, editing, buzzwords

I was ,partially, surprised that there isn't usually a talk about this in SE communities. Nevertheless, science-based sites and learner-and-teacher forums (sorry for the lack of a better term) like chemistry.SE, biology.SE, and ELL.SE (the ones I have an account in) are sometimes flooded with buzzwords inside the question bodies, but not the titles. These "buzzwords" usually come from new users, but sometimes (not often here) come from experienced ones too. So enough with the talk and let's dig into the question:

Firstly, I would want to classify issues that are usually seen in questions:

## Class A: Fine buzzwords

Are usually at the beginning of the statements or are the approximately exact copies of the question title. Don't usually cause problems, especially when in the latter one the question is pretty well-though and well-polished. These can even sometimes affect the body of the questions.

> I know this is a very easy question, but....
>
> I need to...
>
> Please clarify me this statement from [a citable reference]
>
> What happens if I/you... (way more often here)
>
> Question title: Why is this compound...? Question body: Why is this compound...?

## Class B: Fine declarations

Usually new users that are active in other SE communities use this kind of vocabulary. Attacking someone or demonstrating low knowledge in advanced chemistry, in a search for a fathomable answer or thanking the answerer are the main concepts. They're not effective on the body of the question.

> Our teacher can't teach the greatest.
>
> I have only my knowledge of chemistry from high school.
>
> Chemistry is not my main topic, so ....
>
> Thanks in advance.
>
> Your help is really appreciated.

## Class C: Where the issue rises

> I'm very poor in chemistry. Please help.
>
> I need help. PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE...!
>
> How can I get the answer to this question please? (Usually homework questions that get closed)

These are not needed in questions at all, and never will be. They're simply giving a viewer of the question a negative first impression towards the post and the poster.

The first type is usually ignored, the second type is only deleted if you want your edit summary to be more than 6 characters (:D) and the third type is never seen to have changed.

What should be done about these? I know the question seems trivial but I get doubtful when starting to edit sth.

Comment: Get rid of everything distracting! If you edit something, do it thoroughly. I usually remove all unnecessary bold and/ or italic statements in the process. However, since every post edited will be bumped to the top, it should be avoided doing a lot of questions in one go. Also I would consider the sole purpose of removing a "thanks" statement as a too minor an edit to be justified. If you make changes like the mentioned, make sure to include the reason in the edit summary, so that people understand what you did and why you did it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar to [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed), I suggest you edit them out.

Do they add to the actual *question*? If so, keep them. If not (which is usually the case), they can be removed.