# I am asking about chemistry, you know, that's why I put it in the title

Tags: discussion, editing, question-titles, buzzwords

**Previously on 'Never mind the Buzzwords':**

1. [I question the use of "question" in question titles](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/524/4945) ([search here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Aquestion))
2. [Help make help questions have more helpful titles](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/549/4945) ([search here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Ahelp))
3. [Houston, we have a "Problem" in question titles](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/566/4945) ([search here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Aproblem))
4. [Buzzwords in question titles - season 4 & 5 - experiments and exercises](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/583/4945)
   ([search here for experiments](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Aexperiment))
   ([search here for exercises](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Aexercise+))
5. [Can we edit out unnecessary "statements of weakness" or buzzwords inside the questions' bodies?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/593/4945)

From the network that brought you smash hits like 'Breaking Bad questions': The sixth season of **Nevermind the Buzzwords**. It's a game changer.

There has been and will always be a significant amount of buzzwords in question titles. Ultimately to the point where they are not helpful at all. Since all question on this website are supposed to be about chemistry, it may as well qualify as the worst one.
In this context, let's play a little game. I'll give you three question titles (with positive score, not closed, no homework) and you guess what it is about. If you get it right, good for you. If you get it wrong, well, that's the point, isn't it.

1. [Reduction and oxidation in organic chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/31488/revisions)
2. [Organic Chemistry Hazards](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/35128/revisions)
3. [Mathematical Statistics and Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/21922/revisions)

I admit that some of the uses are legit, especially in high (>10) scoring questions. Some of the mid range question definitely could use a more descriptive title and most of the homework type questions have meaningless titles as place holders. But that was/ is/ will be an issue in previous and upcoming seasons. If you have some spare time, help out by giving some better titles to questions, that deserve it:

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Achemistry

On second glance there is a similar query, that is just as meaningless as the above. Many of the really bad examples contain the phrase "chemical reaction" in one variation or the other. Hence another query, that will give you plenty of editing points is:

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Achemical*

Some of the posts just desperately need a flag and a down vote. Some of them can be closed if they are not already. If you have one to spare, go ahead. After all, we just want to keep the quality high.

Even if the question looks like a really bad one, it could be a good idea to check if it has a good answer, because then it is still a good idea to edit them. If your edits have to be reviewed, make sure you mention that in the summary to make them get approved easier.

**Thank you for your attention.**

Comment: Do we$\,\ldots$ need to hold a chat event for this? *Kidding BTW*

Comment: "Stoichiometry" is another keyword to look out for... a lot of the titles are something like, "stoichiometry help" or "stoichiometry question."