Why was this user's question downvoted?
I noticed that this question received a lot of downvotes.
It seemed like a sincere question with a reasonable amount of effort and thought put up although there was a clear scientific gap which got addressed by the answer. The answerer of the question also claims they don't understand the source of downvotes.
It doesn't appear the question was a duplicate nor does it appear the community was articulating complaints such as "question not clear", "question ill posed" or even voting to close etc... and it did garner a high quality answer. My experience on physics.se, math.se, and mathoverflow is usually such a question will get at the least 0 upvotes but rarely so many negative votes. I would like to better understand what is poor about this question so I can avoid making similar mistakes myself.

For starters https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3389/i-have-a-doubt-about-doubt-in-doubt-titles

@Mithoron So he’s getting a down-vote right out the gate because he learned English in India? That hardly seems fair.

I cannot answer for all downvoters - there appear to be numerous reasons people downvote. Please read What to do about rudimentary questions?
